# file.write() in python

Tags: python

```
import os
import sys
import re
import string

f=open('./iprange','r')
s=f.readline()
f.close()
pattern='inet addr:'+s
pattern=pattern.split('x')[0]
pattern='('+pattern+'...'+')'

os.system('ifconfig -a >> interfaces')
f=open('./interfaces','r')
s=f.readline()

while (len(s))!=0:
    i=re.search(pattern,s)
    if i!=None:
        sp=re.split(pattern,s)[1]
        ip=re.split('inet addr:',sp)[1]
        break
    s=f.readline()

f.close()
os.system('rm ./interfaces')
f=open('./userip','w')
f.write(ip)
f.close()

NameError;name 'ip' is not defined
```

I split `pattern` by `s` and store the result in `sp`, then I find the IP address and store the result in `ip`. But the error says `ip` is not defined - what's going on?

Comment: It's sufficient to write: `while s:` instead of `while (len(s))!=0:` because `bool('') == False` and `bool('any_string') == True`

Answer (score 3):

```
while (len(s))!=0:
    i=re.search(pattern,s)
    if i!=None:
        sp=re.split(pattern,s)[1]
        ip=re.split('inet addr:',sp)[1]
        break
    s=f.readline()
```

The ip assignment is inside the if closure, which is apparently never being executed.

Comment: I have declared ip as global still error global name ip is not defined

Comment: So how to write the value of ip in file?

Comment: `ip` is already global; The problem is that your while loop exists without assigning it (the search is never successful)

Comment: How to assign in while loop then?

Comment: Well, just make sure the search is successful and the if closure is executed!

Comment: Give me the way to write value of ip in file?

Comment: ip has NO VALUE; You try to assign the result of the search to it, but because the search is never successful (i is always none) ip has no value. Check your regex so the search succeeds.

Comment: @pythonm I think you mean "if block" not "if closure". A closure is something different.

Comment: So see where you have `break`? Open the file for write *there* because you know that right then there is a value assigned to `ip`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something more like this:

```
import os
import sys
import re
from itertools import takewhile

with open('./iprange','r') as f:
    s = f.readline()

prefix = 'inet addr:'
pattern = prefix + s
pattern = pattern.split('x')[0]
pattern = '(%s...)' % pattern

os.system('ifconfig -a >> interfaces')
with open('interfaces', 'r') as f:
    # Put all lines up to the first empty line into a list
    # http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile
    # `[line.rstrip() for line in f]` could be a generator instead:
    # (line.rstrip() for line in f)
    lines = list(takewhile(lambda x: x, [line.rstrip() for line in f]))
os.remove('interfaces')

for s in lines:
    if re.search(pattern, s):
        sp = re.split(pattern, s)[1]
        ip = sp[len(prefix):]
        with open('./userip', 'w') as f:
            f.write(ip)
        break
else:
    print "No match found"
```

For one thing, you only write to the file `userip` if you find a match and you get a message if no match was found.